# Express polynomial in terms of one coefficient

Tags: polynomials, diophantine-equations, factoring

Take the polynomial

$$2 a b n^2 - a^2 b^2 n$$

where $n$ is the variable, and coefficients $a$ and $b$ are integers.

Is it possible to derive an expression for $b$ in terms of $a$ and $n$, or an expression for $a$ in terms of $b$ and $n$?

UPDATE:

It seems I wasn't as clear as I thought. My bad. Here is what I meant to say... Given the expression $2 a b n^2 - a^2 b^2 n$, is it possible to completely factor out either $a$ or $b$ so that, for two functions $f$ and $g$, the expression $2 a b n^2 - a^2 b^2 n$ can be rewritten as

$$2 a b n^2 - a^2 b^2 n=f(b)g(a,n)$$

or

$$2 a b n^2 - a^2 b^2 n=f(a)g(b,n)$$

Hopefully that's clearer. You were right to pull me up. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by an expression for $b$ in terms of $a$ and $n$? As it stands, you only have a polynomial, not an equation. There is no relation between $a$, $b$ and $n$ because there is no relation/equation to begin with.

Comment: @Servaes, I am not sure why you say  to the OP "you only have a polynomial, not an equation". My understanding is that polynomial is a type of equation after all.

Comment: pol·y·no·mi·al
/ˌpäləˈnōmēəl/
 Learn to pronounce
adjective
1.
consisting of several terms.
noun
1.
MATHEMATICS
an expression of more than two algebraic terms, especially the sum of several terms that contain different powers of the same variable(s).

$$$$


nothing about an equation in there. an equation only happens with an equals sign. An inequality, only happens with signs like less than or equal,strictly less than, greater than or equal, or strictly greater than. some other notations have similar symbols for not necessarily being equal to the whole thing.

Comment: You want "an expression of b in terms of....", well, this is not clear.  You already have f(b)=$2 a b n^2 - a^2 b^2 n$.

Comment: no you don`t, if anything it would be $f(n)$ , and without a relation to something else we have nothing to relate the variables with.

Comment: Please see update. Thank you for looking. The error was mine.

Comment: @NoChance A polynomial is a formal expression that is a sum of products of powers of indeterminates with some coefficients. It is not an equation, just as $\sin(x)$ is not an equation, and $\tfrac{u}{v}$ is not an equation.

Comment: @Servaes, this is new and strange to me. I will assume you are correct. Thank you for the information.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Given only $2abn^2-a^2b^2n$, let's assume standard form $2a^2b^2n-2abn^2+0=0$. Then we can use the quadratic equation to solve for either $a$ or $b$, here solved for $a$.

$$a=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}=\frac{2bn^2\pm\sqrt{(2bn^2)^2-4(b^2n)(0)}}{2(2b^2n)}=\frac{2bn^2\pm 2bn^2}{2(2b^2n)}=\frac{4bn(n)\lor 0}{4bn(b)}=\frac{n}{b}\lor0$$
Since the powers of $a$ and $b$ are the same, $b=\frac{n}{a}\text{ or }0$ and this answers the original question. I'm not sure what you want to do with the part about f(a)g(...

Answer (score 2):

Suppose there exist function $f$ and $g$ such that
$$2 a b n^2 - a^2 b^2 n=f(a)g(b,n).$$
First note that if $n$ is nonzero, then for any nonzero $b$ with $b\neq2n$ we have
$$f(1)g(b,n)=2bn^2-b^2n=bn(2n-b)\neq0,$$
so in particular $g(b,n)\neq0$. Then also $bn$ is nonzero and $b\neq 2bn$, so $g(b,bn)\neq0$ and
$$f(2n)g(b,bn)
=2\cdot(2n)\cdot b\cdot(bn)^2-(2n)^2\cdot b^2\cdot(bn)=0,$$
which shows that $f(2n)=0$ for all nonzero $n$. But for all nonzero $n$ we also have
$$f(n)g(n,n^2)=2\cdot n\cdot n\cdot n^4-n^2\cdot n^2\cdot n^2=n^6\neq0,$$
a contradiction. Hence no such functions $f$ and $g$ exist.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you @Servaes for taking the time to explain so clearly.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to do with a question like this is to just try some numbers.

Here are values of the polynomial for a few values of $a,$ $b,$ and $n.$
\begin{array}{cccc}
a&b&n&2abn^2-a^2b^2n\\
1&1&1&1\\
1&1&2&6\\
1&2&1&0\\
1&2&2&8
\end{array}

From the third row, we see that if the polynomial can be expressed as the product $f(b)g(a,n),$ either $f(2)=0$ or $g(1,1)=0.$
But the first row requires that $g(1,1)\neq0,$
and the fourth row requires that $f(2)\neq0.$
There is no way to reconcile these three rows.

The polynomial is symmetric in $a$ and $b,$
so we know even without further checking that $f(a)g(b,n)$ also will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Above equations shown below:

$2 a b n^2 - a^2 b^2 n=w=f(b)g(a,n)$  -----$(1)$

$2 a b n^2 - a^2 b^2 n=w=f(a)g(b,n)$  ------$(2)$

Equations (1) & (2) has solutions:

$(a,b,n,w)=[(p^2),(q^2),(p^2q^2),(p^6q^6)]$

$g(a,n)=(an^2)=(p^6q^4)$

$g(b,n)=(bn^2)=(p^4q^6)$

$f(a)=(a)=(p^2)$

$f(b)=(b)=(q^2)$